# Select sibling th from td (horizontal row heading) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to reference a **th** relating to a **td** within the same **tr**, unfortunately the headers and classes do not correspond so I cannot just create another .each loop.

I've had a play with adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523770/how-can-i-get-the-corresponding-table-header-th-from-a-table-cell-td) which references a vertical heading but with no success.

Thanks all for your help.

---

**Example Row**

```
<tr>
<th id="row_51_18" class="level3 levelodd item b1b column-itemname" colspan="1"><a title="Link to Quiz activity" href="http://virtualmedics.org/mod/quiz/grade.php?id=93&amp;itemnumber=0&amp;userid=18"><img class="icon itemicon" alt="Quiz" title="Quiz" src="http://virtualmedics.org/theme/image.php?theme=vmelegance&amp;amp;component=quiz&amp;amp;image=icon">Acute Appendicitis</a></th>
<td headers="cat_23_18 row_51_18 percentage" class="level3 levelodd item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage">79 %</td>
<td headers="cat_23_18 row_51_18 average" class="level3 levelodd item b1b itemcenter  column-average">65 %</td>
<td headers="cat_23_18 row_51_18 feedback" class="level3 levelodd item b1b feedbacktext column-feedback">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
$("[id^=cat_]").each(function(i,obj){


var gatherLabels = [];
var gatherValues = [];


$('td[headers*="' + obj.id + '"]').each(function(i, obj) {

    if ($(obj).hasClass("column-percentage")) {
        gatherLabels.push(obj.closest('tr').child('th').innerText); // 'undefined'
        gatherValues.push(obj.innerText.replace('%', '')); // Working fine
    }

});
```

---

**Questions**

1. How can I select the text within the corresponding th for each td
2. Is declaring obj twice (within both .each) an awful thing to do.... seems to not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that within the `.each` call the variable `obj` is a plain DOM `<td>` element, and that the `<th>` is the first (element) child of the enclosing `<tr>`:

```
var th = obj.parentNode.firstElementChild;
```

As `th` is also a plain DOM element you can continue to access its `innerText` attribute directly.

Comment: Do be aware that `firstElementChild` is not supported before IE9 - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild