# How do I write a CSS selector for an element that contains other elements?

Tags: css

*Note: I'm not looking for a parent of an element.  I'm looking for an element that contains other elements within it.*

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and I'm using Nokogiri to parse HTMl documents.  I want to find the table in my document whose first row (first tr element) has at least one th element.  How do I write a CSS selector for that?  Note that I only want to select the table, not the th elements themselves.  Here is an example of the table I would hope to select from within the document

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other data</td>
        </tr>
        …
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Parent selectors do not exist in css3. Here is one of many articles on it.  https://www.google.ca/amp/s/css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/amp/?client=ms-android-rogers-ca.  You could try jquery if thats an option kind of like in this answer.  Get table find th get parent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3523794/3366016

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We'd like to see what you tried, not just a sample of your input data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for the parent of an element.  I'm looking for an element htat has an element within it.

Comment: This isn't really a Nokogiri question if you're asking specifically for a CSS selector to find something, it'd be a CSS question and Nokogiri, Ruby and Rails aren't appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `Array#select` method that filter all the tables where the first `tr` contains a `th` element.

For example, suppose you have a `Nokogiri` object called `doc`:

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

url = # your url
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url))

tables = doc.css("table").select do |table|
  # consider only the first row of each table
  first_row = table.css("tr").first

  # check if that row's children contains a <th> element
  first_row.children.map(&:name).include?("th")
end
```