# Get the identifying header from a table with rowspans and column spans

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

Assuming I have a table with column and row spans I am looking for a way to find the header that uniquely identifies a cell.

For this table:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 
 table, td, th {
   border: 1px solid gray;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">col1</th>
      <th rowspan="2">col2</th>
      <th rowspan="3">col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">col5</th>
      <th>col7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3kqrpt0/

I would like to get the following header

| col5 | col5 | col3 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand completely what do you wish to do. Is this desired output? https://jsfiddle.net/mn1kxp2z/

Comment: Yes that is basically what I am trying to do.

Comment: Browsers are actually already doing this in the background, but I doubt there is an interface to access that information. What are you trying to achieve? You are not trying to replace the spanning headers by single cells, or are you?

Comment: To me it seems that the result you present in your question is not corresponding to the semantics of the used headers. This makes it impossible to provide reusable code. A single cell can have multiple headers, you can be explicit about that by means of the [`headers` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-headers). If you did that, you could easily access those headers by means of javascript.

Comment: This might help: [...table header from a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139306/2743458)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you have to do is -

- Inside table, create **thead** element, which stands for *table head*
- Create new table row - **tr**, which is going to be filled with column headers that you need
- And lastly, add those **th** *(table header)* elements that you need.

Then, in the body of the table you go the same way, just with different elements:

- Create **tbody** element
- Create **tr** element
- Fill **tr** with table data - **td**

Here is the code snippet.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>col5</th>
   <th>col5</th>
   <th>col3</th>
   <th>col7</th>
 </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>value</td>
   <td>value1</td>
   <td>value2</td>
   <td>value3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```